# Resubmit FB app for review

Tags: facebook

I have a problem with my app.

It's currently "Pending approval".

I have accidentally submitted "Ads Management Basic Access" for review a few weeks ago and totally forgot about it. At the moment the app can't be used by people who are not testers or developers.

The problem is - i can't resubmit the app for review again. I have to mark additional features that i want the FB team to review in order for the app to be submitted for review again.

Any ideas on how to solve this? Would it be easier to just create new identical app?

Comment: Unclear what you’re asking; if you submitted including items that you don’t think you need any more now, and it hasn’t been reviewed yet – them simply cancel the submission.

Comment: why can't you cancel it? is it not there under 'Items in Review' section of your app's 'Status & Review' tab?